# Selenium cannot click onto table row even though manually it works

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My page has a table. The rows get dynamically loaded into the table through an API call. A row in the finished table looks like this

```
<tr class="ant-table-row ant-table-row-level-0" data-row-key="0">
  <td class="">Value1</td>
  <td class="">Value2</td>
  <td class="">Value3</td>
  <td class="">Value4</td>
</tr>
```

I want selenium to click on the first row. My code looks like this:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ant-table-row-level-0')))
time.sleep(3)
rows = self.selenium.find_elements_by_class_name("ant-table-row-level-0")
rows[0].click()
```

I get the error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view

When the selenium browser builds up, I can see the table and I can click on the row (and then one div that was invisible becomes visible). So when I manually do it, it works, but selenium somehow has problems clicking on this row.

I also increased the timer to 10 and 20 seconds without success and I tried this just to verify I am clicking at the right row:

```
td = self.selenium.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
  for t in td:
    if "Value1" in t.get_attribute("innerHTML"):
      t.click()
```

Nothing works. The onclick listener for the table is on the row itself. So clicking on a td tag should also trigger something.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
td = self.selenium.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
  for t in td:
    if "Value1" in t.get_attribute("innerHTML"):
      t.click()
```

Turns out the above code did work, but does anyone know why the regular thing does not work ?

Comment: it could be because of multiple elements being returned by find_elements_by_class_name("ant-table-row-level-0") and the element at index 0 is not clickable. It is possible because of element overlay.

Comment: I thought so, too, but I printed out len(rows) and got 1. Plus if I put a time.sleep(30) in there and manually clicked on the row in the selenium browser and that worked. So not sure why it is complaining